# Mysql query select non-members

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables:

```
Customers:
- ID
- NAME

Modulemembers:
- ID
- customer_id
- enabled
```

I use this to enable a function of my site for some customers.
I have a form where the admin of the site can add the module for a customer, so i need a query that looks for customers that are NOT member of the modulemembers table.

I made this:

```
SELECT customers.id, 
       customers.name 
FROM   customers, 
       modulemembers 
WHERE  customers_id != modulemembers.cust_id 
ORDER  BY customers.name
```

but it does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` in the `WHERE` clause to get the result:

```
SELECT c.id, 
  c.name 
FROM customers c
WHERE not exists (select customer_id
                  from modulemembers m
                  where c.id = m.customer_id)
order by c.name
```

Comment: this is the best answer of the bunch

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and filter based on `NULLs`. The query below will pull in all results from the `customers` table and the `modulemembers` table. If there is not a match in the `modulemembers` table then the `custid` will be `NULL`.

```
SELECT c.id, c.name 
FROM customers c
    LEFT OUTER JOIN modulemembers m ON c.customers_id = m.cust_id 
WHERE m.custid IS NULL
ORDER BY c.name
```

Comment: both work. `NOT EXISTS` is better here, though because no data is required for `modulemembers`. this is an anti-semijoin that tests for existence only.

Comment: @Max come on now, being more explicit can often outweigh the huge, excruciating cost of typing more. You could also write old-style joins to type less, or SELECT *, etc,

Comment: @AaronBertrand thank you. For me it's more obvious when it says `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. There's no chance for it to be confused with just `JOIN`

Comment: @Matt ah, I had already added `OUTER`, so you rolled back to the edit prior to my addition.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
   SELECT c.ID AS customerId,
          c.NAME AS fullName,
          m.ID AS memberId
     FROM Customers AS c
LEFT JOIN Modulemembers AS m ON m.customer_id = c.ID
    WHERE m.ID IS NULL;
```